# href onclick fail to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line:

```
<li id="menu-item-1542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1542"><a href="contact-us/index.html">Contact </a></li>
```

I need to replace href with onclick but keep the design,etc, this is failing, when mouse over 'Contact' its not showing little hand creating the feeling that 'Contact' its just text,also css is lost:

```
<li id="menu-item-1542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1542" onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('second'))">Contact</li>
```

How to fix it ?
window.smoothScroll code :

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
    var scrollContainer = target;
    do { //find scroll container
        scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
        if (!scrollContainer) return;
        scrollContainer.scrollTop += 1;
    } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

    var targetY = 0;
    do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
        if (target == scrollContainer) break;
        targetY += target.offsetTop;
    } while (target = target.offsetParent);

    scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
        i++; if (i > 30) return;
        c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
        setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
    }
    // start scrolling
    scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Are you writing a JavaScript function for onclick()?

Comment: it's always better to use an anchor tag or button, when you can -- but otherwise, you can use the CSS `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: why would you want to replace with an onclick? never do inline js - it's bad practice

Comment: Although sometimes when I use button it doesn't display pointer so I need to add it as well. @Doug

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is to move cursor to another div located o lower page. i have the working javascript code but onclick is giving me problems.

Comment: The css is lost on the contact, because it is not in <a> tag, which has special design. Add class to the li and check that <a>Contact</a> design in dev tool.

Comment: @marius you can do by using id's - div with id of here can be jumped to like this: `<a href="#here">link</a>`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs thanks, That solved my problem so easy !

Comment: @marius no worries happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

**onclick** only **works** one button tag

Example:
Execute a JavaScript when a button is clicked:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

[Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can do in multiple ways , some are i created below . by keeping href="#" and onClick event anchor tag or directly giving link to li tag by onclick. for verifying onclick i change text color of "Contact" onClick.

```
    <li id="menu-item-1542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1542" 
    onclick="smoothScroll()"> Contact </li>


    <li id="menu-item-1542" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1542">
<a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll()">Contact</a></li>


    <script>

    function smoothScroll (){

    console.log('inside method');
    document.getElementById('second');
    document.getElementById("menu-item-1542").style.color = "red";

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer so can mark this as closed:

JS is a tad overkill and same effect can be achieved with pure HTML:

```
<a href="#my-div">My link</a>

<div id="my-div">content</div>
```

this will jump the page to #my-div on a click